# How to sort characters with their occurrence in a file, alphabetically and also when the amount of occurrence is the same?

Tags: command-line, zsh

So I have, for example, the following output on the Ubuntu terminal:

```
238 E
150 A
88 T
88 R
```

Now I want to sort it from the highest occurrence to the least which I have already done. In addition I also want to do this, for example where T and V come forward 88 times and when this happens, I want to sort those characters alphabetically. So here we get, first 88 R and then comes 88 T. How can I do it on the terminal using commands and/or pipes. (I'm using zsh with Ubuntu if anyone requires this information)

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Read `man sort`. You can sort numerically by the first space-delimited field and alphabetically the second field.

Comment: The default behavior of the GNU `sort -k1,1nr` command should include a "last-resort" lexical sort **unless** you specify `-s` / `--stable`

Comment: Replying to @waltinator: thanks for your reply. I've read the man page of sort multiple times and my problem is also very specific so I couldn't find anything useful there. I would like to know more about "the first space-delimited field and alphabetically the second field", on how to do it. But what I needed was that if and if only two or more same amount of occurrence of character are present, then to only sort those characters alphabetically.

Comment: Replying to @steeldriver: thank you too for your help. I've found the answer/solution by using sort -k 1nr before I had seen your comment. I've seen this option for sort many places but I don't fully understand what it is/does. (Newbie here). Could you maybe also explain what -s/--stable does as I've neer seen/used it myself? Thanks a lot.